# How to reduce copy in c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a `Bytearray` class and want to implement a member function `copy(int start, int end)` that can copy a segment of data and return a new `Bytearray` object. My implementation is

```
Bytearray Bytearray::copy(int start, int end){
    Bytearray b(end - start);
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
        b._data[i-start] = _data[i];
    }
    return b;
}
```

But, as far as I know, if I call `Bytearray aa = bb.copy(1, 5);` it takes 3 times of copying data. One is copy data from `this` to the temporary object `b` . Then it calls copy constructor and `operator =` . How can I decrease copy and improve efficiency.

Comment: It's not going to call both the copy constructor and `operator=`, only one of them. And if the compiler does copy elision you might not even get that.

Comment: Why not both call? Is that the compiler will optimize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't call `Bytearray::operator=()` at all.   The caller might in an expression `x = a.copy(start, end)`.

In practice, most modern compilers will elide temporaries, although - strictly speaking - the standard doesn't require them to.

With C++11, you can provide a move constructor which will more definitely encourage the compiler to elide temporaries.   Without that (e.g. you don't provide a move constructor in C++11, or you're using a pre-C++11 compiler) typical approaches are to pass the destination object by reference

```
void Bytearray::copy(int start, int end, Bytearray& b)
{
   for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
      b._data[i-start] = _data[i];
}
```

or a pointer

```
void Bytearray::copy(int start, int end, Bytearray* b)
{
    // assume b is the address of a valid object
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
        b->_data[i-start] = _data[i];
}
```

Comment: I use `g++4.8` compiler while not use `std=c++11` flag. Do you mean that it only copy once at all with my code?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  Eliding copies (which, in turn, reduces copying operations) is permitted but not required by the standards.   If you want a guarantee, you need to either use techniques like I described, or confirm if your compiler (and set of compiler settings) will elide copies.    This is a matter of compiler quality of implementation, not a case of "all compilers will" or "all compilers won't".

Answer (score 0):

You should implement move constructor and move assignation. It will allow the compiler to move the data instead of copying it. It basically goes like this:

```
Bytearray Bytearray::copy(size_t start, size_t end) {
    Bytearray b; // declare as usual

    return move(b); // the return value is constructed by move
}

// how to use it?
// use it as usual!
// myB is constructed by move.
Bytearray myB = otherB.copy();
```

How to implement this? This is quite easy. It's like a copy constructor, but you steal the data instead of copying it.

```
struct Bytearray {
    Data* _data = nullptr; // null by default
    // _data should be a unique_ptr and declared like this : 
    // unique_ptr<Data> _data;

    // unique_ptr works with array too.


    // move constructor
    Bytearray (Bytearray&& other) {
        // we have the other's data, the other becomes null.
        swap(_data, other._data);
    }

    // move assignation
    Bytearray& operator=(Bytearray&& other) {
        // same thing here, we swap the data.
        swap(_data, other._data);
        // as we swap, we get the new data. 
        // Since other is temporary, our old data is deleted by other destructor.
        // No leak here.
    }

        // you could mark copy constructor and copy assignation as deleted here.
};
```

Here you go! No more copy and no more pointer and reference.

Comment: It seems some c++11 features in the code. I know little about c++11. I'm going to learn it. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score -1):

Below is one typical way of doing it.

```
void Bytearray::copy(int start, int end, Bytearray* b){
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
    b->_data[i-start] = _data[i];
  }
}

...

Bytearray aa(4);
bb.copy(1, 5, &aa);
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to take the result as a parameter(I dislike that style). But it only copies one time at all. Maybe I will choose it eventually.  (I think Bytearray& may be better.)

Comment: One common convention (e.g. in the Google style guide https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments) is that inputs are const references and outputs are pointers.